# War dogs fighting each other

Tags: dwarf-fortress

I recently had two war dogs chained up next to each other, guarding the entrance of my fortress. Suddenly I noticed blood and body parts covering the hallway and, checking the <kbd>r</kbd>eports, it turned out the war dogs had somehow turned on each other, one managing to kill the other.

I've never experienced this before - I was under the impressions dogs were automatically "domestic" and can't revert to a wild state. If that's the case, what triggered this fight? A bug or a feature?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Crowded animals will fight, perhaps that was the reason, though I don't know what constitutes being crowded and the behavior isn't well documented - the best i could find is a sentence in [this DF wiki article](http://dwarffortresswiki.org/index.php/DF2012:Nest_box#Incubation_Chamber).

Comment: Interesting - they were chained either side of a 3 tile wide corridor. I'm not sure if that counts as crowded, but its good to know

Comment: I think being crowded for animals is occupying a square with another animal in it. If that's the case, putting one of the restraints 3 tiles down the corridor from the other one should avoid such deaths without significantly lowering detection rate.

Comment: Even better, you should be able to chain them on either side of a 4-tile wide corridor and still have perfect detection of thieves and snatchers.